# Trying to find a way that will enable me have distict colour in my plots even though the colors are continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

Is there a way that one can use the color palettes that are up to 20 distinct categories? I am using the wesanderson package but since the colors are continuous, they don't come out as distinct. What should I add in this code to make my colors distinct.

```r
scale_fill_manual(values=wes_palette(n=23, name = "Royal1", type = "continuous"))
```

Comment: is the variable you are colouring based on continuous or discrete? it is hard to help without any data

Comment: It would be useful to help you having a reproducible data set

Comment: thank you so much. I found the solution to the problem.